# Laravel: Pass current view name to View Composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade file in Laravel, called products.blade.php. Inside of that file, I'm including a sub-view, which displays data from the database. The sub-view is fetching the data using a View Composer (to avoid writing the same code everywhere I need to display that data).

Is it possible to pass the name of the "main" view to that View Composer?

In my AppServiceProvider I have this code:

```
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        view()->share('view_name', $view->getName());
    });
```

So the sub-view knows the name of the parent view. I've tried:

```
@include('sub-view.name', ['parent' => $view_name])
```

and tried to access that `parent` variable in the View Composer but I get: `Undefined variable: parent`.

I've also tried `$view->getName()` in the compose method of the View Composer, however it gives me the name of the `sub-view` and I need the `parent`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `View::composer` in controller to share data with view composer. Will that help?

Comment: I've ended up using: `$view->getData()` in the View Composer to retrieve all data passed to the view, including the view_name variable

Comment: So did you got parent views name in it?

Comment: Exactly, but just because I'm passing it in the AppServiceProvider. Basically all that data that the view has access, is accessible via `$view->getData()`, including `view_name` (the one that I'm passing in the AppServiceProvider)

Comment: You shouldn’t be doing that. A view composer shouldn’t know what view it is composing. If you need to pass the view name to a composer, then you’re doing something wrong. Just like a view shouldn’t know what controller is rendering it, a view shouldn’t know what composers are attached to it. A composer should just give view some data.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in this case I have a main view and a "sub-view" file. The sub-view needed to fetch and display different data from the database depending where it is inserted (or in other words, depending on who is the parent). The only way I could think of was making the view composer aware of who was the parent and then making it fetch the right records from the database. Otherwise I would need to duplicate the sub-view code everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the view data is accessible by using `$view->getData()` method.

So in the view composer you can do

```
class MyCustomComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $currentView = $view->getData()['view_name'];

        // Do something
    }
}
```